# Get active filters from Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

Is there some easy / convenient way (or maybe a view method) to get a list of the active filters currently being used by Ransack? I cannot find any documentation on how to access the current search and find information on what relationships are being queries/filtered.

I know I can access the search object and find the conditions like so:

```
@q.conditions
```

But this only gives me an array of the relationship fieldname, with no easy way to access the related model.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: I need to know the same thing. Did you find a way?

Comment: No, I don't think I did.